# disable internet explorer console from javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console, ie-developer-tools

Is it possible to disable the IE developer console?
I tried this

```
 <script type="'text/javascript'">
 (function(){

var _z = console;
Object.defineProperty( window, "console", {
get : function(){
    if( _z._commandLineAPI ){
    throw "Sorry, Can't exceute scripts!";
        }
    return _z; 
},
set : function(val){
    _z = val;
}
});

})();
</script>
```

but didn't work

Comment: I don't think you can, let's wait for an answer.

Comment: I can tell you how to disable IE..

Comment: Why would you want to disable it? Disabling it will only make your own development harder? (And it won't work to block access to scripts: one can just download the script directly and look at it with other tools.)

Comment: Change `window` to `eval`, Object.defineProperty( **eval**, "console", { ...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

You can't force a browser (not) to do something like that.

Even if it were possible, the user always has access to the scripts you send to the browser. Besides, it's relatively easy to write a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that adds a input element to the page that can serve as impromptu console.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are doing this to prevent users from executing arbitrary code on your page. Like others have mentioned, there will always be ways to circumvent this kind of artificial restrictions (ex: bookmarklets). You should instead focus on Server-side validation and treat all data that comes from the user as suspect.

That said... If you are hard-set on disabling JS execution from the console, disable the EVAL statement (which the F12 console uses to evaluate script).

Example:

```
eval = function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to disable the F12 tools is via the registry:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools]
"Disabled"=dword:00000001

Which can also be set by group policy as documented "Turn Off Developer Tools".

This won't help you as a web site owner block F12 but if you're in an enterprise it's an option. But really your page is running on the clients machine and they can use any number of techniques to interact with it if they want to put the effort in.

Note: You can hack things to try to break the tools but that's not a supported mechanism to disable it :).